# Try - Double Catch Statement Java

Tags: java, exception

I am having an issue not understanding the error message I am getting from my try - catch statement, which has two catches.

I believe everything is correct, however, I am getting an error `exception X is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement.`

I believe the code is correct, but both of the catch clauses are being rejected!

```
@PUT
@Path("{id}")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response updatePerson(@PathParam("id") int id, String is) {
    try {
        Person person = readPerson(is);
        person.setId(id);
        Person locPerson = persons.get(id);
        if(locPerson == null){
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        persons.put(person.getId(), person);

        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it only java,OR JSON inclusive??? Please add proper tags.

Comment: it looks like either jsonexception or parseexception will never throw within your try block thats why ide complaining agaist it

Comment: Please, when you get an error message, DO NOT edit or otherwise modify it when posting here.  You substituted `X` for the name of the exception the compiler was complaining about.  This is a BIG no-no.  Never obfuscate crucial parts of error messages (removing sensitive text _you_ originated is OK, but that's all).

Comment: Additionally to what Jim Garrison posted, you have a method, `readPerson(String)` that is not included.  I assume this method throws a `ParseException` but we can't be sure. Additionally, your code could throw a WebApplicationException, but your method does not indicate that. A client calling your `updatePerson()` method could get this exception but not able to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the methods called in your try block may throw JSONException or ParseException, you shouldn't catch those exceptions. That's what `exception X is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement` means.

Comment: If, by use of generics or other means, a method might throw an exception which is not specified via `throws` clause (may sometimes be needed when passing a method to another method which will execute it, and the passed method might throw a checked exception which should percolate through the other) is there any "nice" way to catch such exceptions?

Comment: @supercat I don't think a method can throw a checked exception that is not specified in its `throws` clause. If you pass a method to another method that will execute it, the method that executes the passed method must handle all checked exceptions that the passed method may throw (or declare them in its own `throws` clause).

Answer (score 0):

it means the exception you are trying to catch is never going to be thrown inside the try block, so its redundant to have it in the catch statement -> warning as error